# Modifier key press as trigger

Tags: xaml

I need certain elements to change look (change color, add text, etc...) when user holds SHIFT key to show it will affect that item.

Not all items will have same DataContext so I believe I can not just bind it to one DependencyProperty in MainWindow.

Each will have something like

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{[ShiftPressed]"} Value="True">
    <Setter [change color/add text/...]/>
</DataTrigger>
```

How would you do it? Would that affect performance much if a lot of ListBoxItems listened it?

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to use the data trigger to bind to a Boolean property called something like "IsShiftPressed", and use the the visual state manager, along with the DataStateBehaviour to toggle between two states for each of your controls: a normal state, and a shifted state.

Your various controls would then be listening to a single bool property change, rather than implementing multiple key triggers. You'd have more control over when and how that state is triggered.

If you were concerned about performance, I'm not sure how WPF handles things like this under long list scenarios, but providing your lists are virtualised in the list boxes, there shouldn't be any major performance hits to worry about using the state manager.

UPDATE: just realised that you already have the Boolean property defined in your question. Sorry about that!